# Increase icons margin in nautilus

Tags: gnome, 18.04, nautilus

I have an issue with nautilus in 18.04. I could not able to right click on an empty area of the folder window to get context menu, because there is no enough margins between folders/files icons.

The following screenshot demonstrates the situation very well, in which, four adjacent icons are selected and there is no any empty space between them:

[image]

Comment: Looks like an issue with the GTK+ theme you're using. Consider reporting a bug to the theme's developer(s).

Comment: @pomsky I don't think that it is a theme bug, because changing theme to any other theme including the default one results the same issue. Additionally, this issue is not exist with PCManFM.

Comment: But I cannot reproduce this on my 18.04 installation with default themes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLtwW.png

Comment: So, it could be miss-configuration or configuration's conflict on my machine, because I have upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 by new installation in which I kept  `/home` without format and I taken the same old user.